# Getting every slice of a list

Tags: python

I've been through itertools inside and out and I cannot figure out how to do the following. I want to take a list.

`x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` and I want to get a new list:

```
y = [[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],.......[2],[2,3],[2,3,4].....[8]]
```

I need a list of all slices, but not combinations or permutations.

`x = list(zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))` is close, but doesn't do exactly what I'm hoping

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use `combinations` not of `x`, but of the `range` of possible slice indices (including one past the end, thus `len(x)+1`, since slices are exclusive on the end) to make the slice end points, then use them to slice `x`:

```
from itertools import combinations

y = [x[s:e] for s, e in combinations(range(len(x)+1), 2)]
```

That gets exactly what you're going for as straightforwardly as possible. If you want (possibly) faster `map` based code, you can rephrase it as (`list` wrapper unnecessary on Python 2):

```
from itertools import combinations, starmap

y = list(map(x.__getitem__, starmap(slice, combinations(range(len(x)+1), 2))))
```

which gets the same result, but without any Python bytecode execution per-item, which *might* run faster (implementation dependent).

Comment: BTW, at least on my CPython 3.5 install, the listcomp is faster (only 2%ish) for the example input (length 8 `list`), but scales *slightly* worse as the input grows (for a length 100 `list`, it's ~5% slower than the "push to C" `map` based solution). That said, the listcomp is *much* more readable to my mind, so I'd prefer it in general. I leave the other one there just as an alternate example for fun.

Comment: Does this include slices where the start is greater than or equal to the end?

Comment: @jpmc26: No, because that would produce a bunch of empty `list`s in the output. `combinations` returns lexicographically ordered combinations (without replacement) of the input, so it produces `0` with `1` through `len(x)` (inclusive, thanks to +1), then `1` with `2` through `len(x)`, etc. Unlike nested loops over `range`s, it doesn't have to create a bunch of `range` objects (in the inner loop) with varying bounds to do it either, which saves more Python level work and avoids temporaries (the two-`tuple`s it's returning are cached and reused, so they effectively cost nothing).

Comment: Okay. I understand. Was confusing permutations and combinations. ;) But your explanation isn't quite on target, I don't think. The only reason they're sorted is because `range`'s output is. Try, for example, using `combinations(sorted(range(8+1), reverse=True), 2)`. Then all the tuples will start with the larger value. `combinations` seems to go by the input's order, so this depends on that detail of `range`.

Comment: @jpmc26: The terminology is confusing (two orderings are involved, order of tuples and order within tuples), but to be clear: The `tuple`s are emitted in lexicographic ordering, but they themselves are only internally in sorted order if the input was as well. Per the docs: "Combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order. So, if the input iterable is sorted, the combination tuples will be produced in sorted order." So yes, `range` being in order is important, but that's a property of standard `range`s I didn't feel required explanation.

Answer (score 7):

You can utilize list comprehension if you insist on a one-liner:

```
> x=[1,2,3,4]
> [x[a:b+1] for a in range(len(x)) for b in range(len(x)) if a<=b]
```

> [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3], [3, 4], [4]]

Or you can even get rid of that `if`:

```
> [x[a:b+1] for a in range(len(x)) for b in range(a, len(x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
y = [x[b:i+1] for b in range(len(x)) for i in range(len(x))]
final_list = list(filter(lambda x:x, y))
```

Output:

```
[[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [2], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [3], [3, 4], [3, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5, 6], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [4], [4, 5], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6, 7], [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [5], [5, 6], [5, 6, 7], [5, 6, 7, 8], [6], [6, 7], [6, 7, 8], [7], [7, 8], [8]]
```

Comment: That's not valid code; your `for`s are backwards (you use `i` before it exists). Even flipping them, it doesn't produce the output you claim.

Comment: Try it again, but run `del i` before you do. Trust me, it's wrong. You can't use `i` to make a `range` before you've defined `i`, and you're accidentally relying on a previous definition of `i` here. Also, side-note: `filter(lambda x: x, ...)` is a (much) slower way to write `filter(None, ...)`; `filter` is documented to use the identity test when the predicate is `None`.

Comment: @ShadowRanger my apologies, there was an `i` variable defined 100 lines above in my terminal! Please see my recent edit. It works now.

Comment: @Ajax1234. Your output does not match what the OP is looking for.

Comment: @Ajax1234: Still *slightly* off; the OP's requested ordering differs. Fixable by reversing your chosen slice indices (to `x[b:i+1]`), though it's still suboptimal since it needs to perform `n**2` loops and slices and then filter out all the empty ones, rather than produce the correct ones in a single pass without making and filtering garbage. You could avoid the excess loops/slices and secondary filter by narrowing the second range: `x[b:i+1] for b in range(len(x)) for i in range(b, len(x))]` though at that point, you've basically just reinvented `itertools.combinations` poorly.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. Or you could just use the [solution given by Eugene Sh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46941638/984421).

Comment: @ekhumoro: Yar. Though until recently, his had a filtering condition rather than using a computed start on the second `range`, so it was `n**2` loops rather than `n+1 choose 2` (asymptotically, that doubles the loop count). Either way, a lot of reinventing of `itertools.combinations` is going on.

Comment: @ShadowRanger. I don't think that's completely fair, given that `itertools.combinations` was only added in python-2.6. Anyway, I think his answer is worth an upvote, even if it doesn't give the most efficient solution possible. It certainly seems to offer the most *readable* solution.

Comment: @ekhumoro: "Only added in Python 2.6"? It's been *nine* years since 2.6 released and code written for earlier Python 2.x generally runs unmodified on 2.6/2.7, so upgrading shouldn't be a major issue; even if you're not on 3.x, I feel confident relying on features from 2.6. I'd argue that using `combinations` is equally readable, though Eugene's answer is perfectly fine (though it's a little uglier on Py2, since using nested `range` instead of `combinations` involves many temporary `list`s of various sizes; thankfully, the overall scaling here is bad enough that it has to be small temporaries).

Comment: @ShadowRanger. That wasn't really my point: it's not *completely* fair to complain about reinventing `combinations` when python didn't have it *until* 2.6. Especially since python's had list comprehensions since 2.0 and itertools didn't arrive until 2.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157521/discussion-between-shadowranger-and-ekhumoro).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good aproach, an iterative way, I could understand it well:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

res = []
ln= len(lst)


for n in range(ln):
  for ind in range(n+1, ln+1):
    res.append(lst[n:ind])
```

Comment: You can limit the loops and avoid the empty test by changing the ranges to `range(len(lst))` (outer `range`) since the start index should always be between 0 and len(lst) - 1, and `range(n+1, len(lst)+1)` (inner `range`) since the end must always be at least one larger than the start and must stop just past the end of the `list` to slice to the end. Then you don't need the `if` test at all.

Comment: @ShadowRanger aaaaaah, I see now! thanks, I was just editing when you finish the edit, thanks so much, I tryed here https://repl.it/NO6k/0