# Quantity of subarrays in a pythonic way

Tags: python

I have this array:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

and I want all the sub arrays you can get except by the single element, in this case:

```
 [1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4].
```

So I have implemented this code:

```
def nSub(nums:list):
    """
    type nums: list
    """
    l_nums = len(nums)
    p = 2
    for i in range(l_nums):
        for j in range(p,l_nums+1): 
            print(nums[i:j])
        p += 1

nSub([1,2,3,4])
```

But although it works, perhaps there is other way to implement this, so I have this question: is there a pythonic way to do this? Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46941498/getting-every-slice-of-a-list, you can easily adapt any of the solutions to start with slices of length 2.

Comment: Do you open to 3rd  library?

Comment: Hello @Daniel Hao, I prefer a base python solution, but if you know a library that accomplish that, I would appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: I saw above post from @ThierryLathuille has provided the good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple list comprehension should do the job:

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

[arr[n1:n2] 
 for n1 in range(0, len(arr) + 1)
 for n2 in range(n1 + 2, len(arr) + 1)]
```

Output:

```
[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [3, 4]]
```

Comment: Thank you @mcsoini for your answer, just a question, how can I integrate this comprehension list with the print function as it integrates in my question code?